# Forum for discussing upcoming games?

Tags: discussion

Is there stackexchange form for discussing upcoming games? This would be useful for those who need help investigating ahead of time of a game is worth the anticipation or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, there is not.  StackExchange is not a forum, I'm afraid.  It's about Q&A.  If talking about unreleased games was on-topic anywhere, it would be here.  We've determined it's not, because Arqade is not a news site.  We're about answering questions about games that can (or were able to) be played.

If you're looking for a place to discuss upcoming games, I'm afraid SE isn't the place.  You can come hang out with us in the [Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), but there's no guarantee that you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: @linuxfreebird I am sure we will see you on The Bridge :D

Comment: I posted a new question changing the focus of the previous question from disucssion to Q&A, as opposed to re editing this one. Would you like me to edit this question instead?

Comment: @linuxfreebird It doesn't change the answer.  We're the SE site to talk about video games.  If you want to talk about developing, that's GameDev.  Everything else is us.

Comment: Is there away to post this question to spark interest in creating a new stack exchange site devoted to upcoming games?

Comment: You can try Area51, but you better have a strong argument as to why it should exist.  We've gone through the discussion about allowing these types of questions, and they came up short.  I'd recommend reading our [arguments](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/what-is-considered-future-here/7290#7290), and if you want to propose a new site, provide reasoning as to why that would be something viable.